# Como recuperar el ultimo Identity en Entify Framework

Tags: entity-framework-6

estoy trabajando con Entity framework, pero no se como recuperar el ultimo identity de la tabla maestro de factura que le insertaron, necesito recuperarlo para pasarlo al detalle, este es mi codigo

StringBuilder acresults = new StringBuilder();
try
{
this.Validate();
this.mbsMSTFAC.EndEdit();

```
        /* Obtener el registro actual de la fuente de datos - */
        SIAFCOREModel.MSTFAC aoentmstfac = (SIAFCOREModel.MSTFAC)mbsMSTFAC.Current;
        /* Validar los registros que cambiaron o se modificaron en el grid actual*/
        foreach (MSTFAC aomstfac in mbsMSTFAC.List)
        {
            moCtx.MSTFACs.Add(aomstfac);
        }
        /* Si no hay Error, guardar el registro actual */
        //moCtx.SaveChanges();
        for (int i = 0; i < mmaster_grdv_020.DataRowCount; i++)
        {
            mmaster_grdv_020.SetRowCellValue(i, "IDEFAC", aoentmstfac.IDEFAC);
        }
        // Recuperar el Ultimo Identity de la cabceza de factura
        using (var Context = new SIAFCOREEntities())
        {
            ClsUltimoIdentity aoCls = new ClsUltimoIdentity();
            var aoFactura = Context.MSTFACs
            aoCls.UltIDEFAC = aoFactura.Include;
        }
        
    }
    /* Validar y presentr la excepcion si es del modelo de datos */
    catch (DbUpdateException ex)
    {
        XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), clsresources.mcErrdtaapp, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    /* Validar y presentar la excepcion diferente al modelo de datos */
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), clsresources.mcErrdtaapp, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

les agradezco su ayuda, salUdos.

AVMB

Comment: Hola puedes explicarte un poquito mas

Comment: Grabo un registro en este caso la cabecera de la factura, necesito el Identity o numero consecutivo que agregue, recuperarlo a como lo hago en SQL Server o parecido a esto:
@Ultimo numero =@@identity_Scope o SCOPE_IDENTITY

espero tus comentarios.

Comment: @alfredo.avmb si es un número consecutivo, bastaría con obtener el último registro mediante un `orderBy` :D

Comment: Estoy usando o el campo es auto incremental de tipo INT y mi duda es que cuando uso ADO o DataSet este llega negativo y en SQL Server lo recupero con la función SCOPE_IDENTITY,  no deberia ser algo igual o asi de sencillo, si estoy mal me corrigen.

Comment: Si llega negativo ya es algo extraño... podrías incluir lo que te responde ADO?